# Chrome Extension - Request Optional Permissions for current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to require tab permission for current origin.
Ex: I'm on http://stackoverflow.com, clicking on badge, then on button from popup, and I should get a prompt box to allow manipulating on this tab.

What I'm doing:

- manifest

  ```
  ...
  "permissions": ["tabs", "contextMenus"],
  "optional_permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ],
  ...
  ```
- popup

  ```
   $('#reqPermision').click(function()
  {
      bg.reqPerm(url);
  });
  ```
- background

  ```
   function reqPerm(url)
  {
      chrome.permissions.request({permissions: ['tabs'], origins: [url]}, function (granted)
      {
          log('permision:', granted)
      });
  }
  ```

What I'm getting:

> Error during **permissions.request**: Optional permissions must be listed in extension manifest.

If I set url manually *(in this ex. https://stackoverflow.com/)* in "optional_permissions" array, all is working how I need.

Comment: There might not be a way to do this yet. What if you use `*://*/*` instead of `<all_urls>`?

Comment: Conform chrome's api it's the same things. Yes, i've already tried it, and the result is the same.

Comment: Then, yeah, you should put in a [feature request](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-fea-02) for the ability to add a domain as an optional permission without listing that domain in your manifest (or by listing a superset of that domain, e.g. `*://*.google.com/*` allows a request for `*://maps.google.com/*`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, you can only request permissions for URLs that have been explicitly listed in the manifest. However, [this feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=93903) should make what you are trying to do (automatically grant permission when clicking on a browser action) doable.

Comment: For the record, the [`activeTab` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) has been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do should work. In the popup the code should be:

```js
$('#reqPermision').click(function() {
    chrome.permissions.request({origins: [url]}, function (granted) {
        log('permision:', granted)
    });
});
```

You don't need to call it from a background page.

---

However it's probably better to use a module like [webext-domain-permission-toggle](https://github.com/fregante/webext-domain-permission-toggle) because it will handle the whole UI for you.

Answer (score -2):

firstly optional permission of  is not allowed //error in your code
secondly you need to specify the tab permission in the array of optional permission
you did this

`"permissions": ["tabs", "contextMenus"],
"optional_permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ],`

you do it like this

`"permissions": [, "contextMenus"],
"optional_permissions": [ 'tabs' ,<any other permission you want>],`

third you should check before it request permission and it not granted then you you should request it
refference [google optional permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions)